# Accessing model properties in Razor-4 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel

I have the following EF generated data model:

```
public partial class PrinterMapping
{
    public string MTPrinterID { get; set; }
    public string NTPrinterID { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
}
```

I then have the following view model:

```
public class PrinterViewModel
{
    public PrinterMapping PrinterMapping;
    public Exceptions Exceptions;
    public IEnumerable<PrinterMapping> Printers;
}
```

In my Index Action in HomeController I am passing my view model to the Index view.

```
private eFormsEntities db = new eFormsEntities();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PrinterViewModel printerModel = new PrinterViewModel();
    printerModel.Printers = from pt in db.PrinterMapping select pt;

    return View(printerModel);
}
```

My Index view is calling a partial view in the following manner towards the end (probably wrong):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/GridView.cshtml")
```

My GridView.cshtml looks like:

```
@model AccessPrinterMapping.Models.PrinterViewModel

<h2> This is Where the Grid Will Show</h2>

@{
    new WebGrid(@model.Printers, "");
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

I learned about the WebGrid method from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx.

My WebGrid line isn't happy at all since it doesn't recognize @model within that line.
How do I access the Printers in the view model that I passed in? Is this even possible?

Thanks very much to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{
    new WebGrid(Model.Printers, "");
}
```

and also you have to pass your model into partial view in

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/GridView.cshtml")
```

in second parameter. I guess this call should be

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/GridView.cshtml", Model)
```

Comment: Thank you all of you. Can you please let me know that happens if I don't pass the Model explicitly to the partial view? It looks like I didn't need to in this case. Secondly what is the difference between @model and Model?

Comment: @model is just a declaration of view Model type. Model is a view property with type, declared in @ model declaration. And also if you don't pass model into partial view, the Model property will be null and you'll get NullReferenceException when you'll use Model property in the GridView.cshtml view.

Comment: Thank you Dmytro for explaining. It looks like I am not getting the NullReferenceException by NOT explicitly passing on the Model to the partial view. But may be it is good practice to do it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Theres two issues with your code.

First, you should explicitly pass your model in like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/GridView.cshtml", Model) @* explicitly pass the model in *@
```

Then, because you are already in a code block in your partial view.. you don't need the @ symbol.. and `Model` has an uppercase M.

```
 new WebGrid(Model.Printers, "");
```

`@model` is a directive for your views/partial views. Think of it as a "configuration" command. `Model` is an actual property. It is the object that is passed into the view.. and is of the type you specified with the `@model` directive.